# How to adjust the length of the window of the Fourier transform with respect to the length of the signal in Python

Tags: python, window-functions, fourier

I ran the following code in Python, setting the window length to 5s, but he reports an error as the window length does not match the signal length. How should I adjust it please?

code:

```
fs = 1000
window_width_samples = int(5 * fs)  #Setting Window length 0.2Hz(5s)
window = parzen(window_width_samples)
windowed_data = accelerate_data_centered[:,0] * window[:, None]
fft_result = abs(rfft(windowed_data[:,1], axis=0))
N = len(accelerate_data_centered[:,1])
frequency_axis = rfftfreq(n=N, d=1 / fs) 
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(frequency_axis, fft_result)
plt.xlabel('频率 (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('振幅')
plt.title('频域图')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

ValueError:

```
x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (173213,) and (5000,)
```

The original paper I want to reproduce is:
In terms of organizing the results of the frequent micromotion measurements, the 20-minute measurements were divided into 20.48-second (4096) data sets, and the respective Fourier amplitude spectra were calculated. In FIGS. 5(b) and (c), the Fourier amplitude spectra of each set of data after division are depicted for the natural foundation F1 and the upper part of the structure S1 overlapping. Here, the effect of a heavy hammer blow as shown in FIG. 5(a) sometimes occurs because the micromotion measurement has been continuously performed during the course of the shock vibration test. In addition, the effect of vibration caused by the passage of a train is sometimes included. In this study, such data were excluded when calculating the Fourier amplitude spectrum (Fig-5(a)). Specifically, the amplitude level of the time-calendar waveform was confirmed for every 20.48 seconds of data, and it was decided not to calculate the Fourier amplitude spectra for data judged to contain time periods that clearly exceeded the component of the amplitude level of the constant micro-motion.
Next, for the calculated Fourier amplitude spectrum, the ratio of the Fourier amplitude spectrum (Fig. 5c) of the upper part of the structure (S1) to the Fourier amplitude spectrum (Fig. 5b) of the natural foundation (F1) was taken. A Parzen window of 0.2 Hz was used for smoothing in calculating the spectral ratio.
[image: Figure-5: Method of organizing the results of constant microtremor measurements((a) Processing of time-calendar waveforms ;(b) Natural Foundation (F1) Response;(c) Response of the upper part of the structure (S1);(d) Ratio of (c) to (b)]

Comment: I’m hesitant to answer this for you because the question shows a clear misunderstanding of the underlying dft theory… you’re windowing the data with a vector of length $5000$. So the FFT result has length $5000$. You therefore need a frequency vector of the same length if you wish to plot the FFT result vs frequency.

Comment: I mean this too, but what I'm sitting on is smoothing the raw signal using a 0.2Hz Parzen window. How should I do this, please?

Comment: I am a doctoral student in geotechnical engineering, and my current research direction is microseismic monitoring and early warning, and I have just come into contact with this direction, so I don't know a lot of theoretical knowledge. Do you have any recommendations for books?

Comment: What I want to do is: All Fourier spectra are smoothed using the Parzen window with a width of 0.2 Hz

Comment: Let’s edit your question with the following: what is your application, I.e. what do you want to get from your analysis? Are you trying to analyze the time data or the frequency data?

Comment: My application is to use the Fourier Transform at Parzen smoothing at 0.2 Hz, I will obtain the smoothed data and analyze the frequency domain data.My ultimate goal is to calculate the spectral ratio of two simultaneous recordings to find the primary excellence frequency of the bridge abutment and in using the formula to calculate the attenuation coefficient.
Another question I have is what is the difference between analyzing time domain and frequency domain data?